# Current file path in webpack

Tags: webpack

Is there any way to receive current file path, like in requirejs?

```
define(['module'], function (module) {
    console.log(module.uri)
});
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yep there is one: [`__filename`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-variables/#__filename-nodejs).

But by default webpack doesn't leak path information and you need to set a config flag to get real filename instead of a mock (`"/index.js"`).

```js
// /home/project/webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  node: {
    __filename: true
  }
}
```

Than you can use `__filename` get the current filename relative to the `context` option:

```js
// in /home/project/dir/file.js
console.log(__filename);
// => logs "dir/file.js"
```

The filename is only embedded into modules where `__filename` is used. So you don't have to be affraid that paths are leaked from other modules.

Comment: Still relevant in 2017: I cannot get this to work when the target is `umd`, so if you're looking for an answer on getting `__dirname` and `__filename` to work with  webpack for a `umd` build, this answer will probably not help you.

Comment: Does this have any impact on performance or any other known side effects to anyone's knowledge? Is there a downside to doing this?

Comment: Just to add. You need to restart the webpack server anytime you update its config for your update to take effect.

Answer (score 7):

To get the filename an the dir name I added this to the web pack config

```
node : {
   __filename: true,
   __dirname: true,
},
```

setting the context to __dirname messed up my web pack config since I have my webpackconfig not placed in root but the paths are setup that way

Answer (score 5):

Try `webpack.DefinePlugin` with `webpack.DefinePlugin.runtimeValue`.
It gives real constants, which can be used in ES6 `import` and `require()`.

Webpack configuration:

```js
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    __NAME: webpack.DefinePlugin.runtimeValue(
        v => {
            const res = v.module.rawRequest.substr(2)
            return JSON.stringify(res); // Strings need to be wrapped in quotes
        }, []
    )
})

// OR

new webpack.DefinePlugin(
    __NAME: webpack.DefinePlugin.runtimeValue(
        v => {
            const res = v.module.rawRequest.substr(2)
            return `'${res.substr(0, res.lastIndexOf('.'))}'`
        }, []
    )
})
```

Source file:

```js
// require "<filename>.html" from "<filename>.js"
const html = require(`./${__NAME}.html`)
```

Comment: This is great! The feature hasn't been documented yet but it was added in https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/6793

Comment: I don't understand how this snippet is related to the question. Please shed more light. 

Thank you.

Comment: Let's have report-1.0.0.js and report-1.0.0.html. Now you can include html into script with require(./${__NAME}.html)