# Injecting variables into webpack

Tags: javascript, requirejs, commonjs, webpack

I'm trying to inject a variable into each module within my webpack bundle in order to have debugging information for JS errors per file.  I've enabled

```
node: {
   __filename: true
}
```

[Current file path in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553868/current-file-path-in-webpack)

in my webpack.config, but I would like to inject something like

```
var filename = 'My filename is: ' + __filename;
```

into each module before compilation.  I've seen the [Banner Plugin](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#bannerplugin) with the `raw` option but it seems this would only inject the banner outside of the webpack closure rather than my desired result of injecting script into each module.

Answer (score 21):

I use variables to resolve a couple of variables in my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      ENVIRONMENT: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'),
      VERSION: JSON.stringify(require('./package.json').version)
    })
]
```

It might not be dynamic enough, but if it is, then you might be able to bypass that loader solution.

Comment: To pass in variables dynamically you can still use this plugin. Just say when building: webpack --define myurl="http://localhost:3000"

Comment: why do you use JSON.stringify on process.env.NODE_ENV?

Comment: If, say, VERSION is used as a variable in code, and JSON.stringify is not used (or another mechanism that added quotes), then you end up with something like this (a compiler error): console.log(VERSION) -> console.log(1.0.0), when you wanted console.log("1.0.0")

Comment: this is the best way to do it i think.

Answer (score 2):

Write your own loader:

**my_project/my_loaders/filename-loader.js:**

```
module.exports = function(source) {
  var injection = 'var __filename = "' + this.resourcePath + '";\n';
  return injection + source;
};
```

Add it to your pipeline and make sure to add also the configuration:

```
resolveLoader: {
  modulesDirectories: ["my_loaders", "node_modules"]
}
```

See the documentation on [how to write a loader](http://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html#writing-a-loader).

Comment: I created this loader https://github.com/optimizely/marketing-website/blob/dfoxpowell/jordan-webpack-try/loaders/inject-filename-loader.js which works great but it is not working for some reason in our prod CI build. I posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850802/webpack-loader-not-working-on-jenkins-ci-build and it's driving me crazy if you have any ideas?