# Webpack Loader not Working on Jenkins CI Build

Tags: javascript, jenkins, gruntjs, docker, webpack

I'm trying to integrate Weback into my current project and am having problems with a custom loader I built to create a concat banner and footer around each module's file contents, and to inject the `__filename`value. Everything works great doing local builds with grunt

https://github.com/optimizely/marketing-website/tree/dfoxpowell/jordan-webpack-try/grunt/webpack

`grunt server
//or
grunt build --env=production //production build for uglify/dedupe`

Our staging build on Jenkins successfully runs the loader using `grunt staging-deploy --branch=$branch --env=production`

Our production build uses a Docker container and a deploy.sh script which runs `grunt build --env=production`. This build for some reason fails to run the loader although `grunt build --env=production` locally will successfully run the loader and build the assets.

I resorted to hardcoding the loader into the repo and requiring it by path in the `make-webpack.config.js` in order to debug if this was some sort of installation issue on Jenkins but this didn't help.

https://github.com/optimizely/marketing-website/blob/dfoxpowell/jordan-webpack-try/loaders/inject-filename-loader.js

I know this is most likely a difficult question to answer without access to our Jenkins deploy environment but any info you could offer for help debugging would be extremely helpful.

I created an issue in the Weback repo [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1008) that basically states the same info as above.

**Update**
I took this suggestion [Injecting variables into webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28145397/injecting-variables-into-webpack#29858423) and added

```
resolveLoader: {
  modulesDirectories: ['loaders', 'node_modules'],
  extensions: ['', '.loader.js', '.js']
}
```

to my webpack.config and put my `loaders` directory in the root of my project. Unfortunately, the result is still the same and the loader doesn't run in prod on Jenkins.

Comment: Try using an absolute path to loaders directory.

Comment: I actually did that here https://github.com/optimizely/marketing-website/blob/3b71dac02d7e511903f16dab002a341705ff1884/grunt/webpack/make-webpack-config.js#L5 used `require.resolve` to get the full path to the loader `var injectFilenamePath = require.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'loaders/inject-filename')).replace('.js', '');` still had the same issue :-(

Comment: your link is broken

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I found to this issue:

Our CI build was installing our project from Git as a `node_module` through NPM rather than using `git clone`. Therefore, there was a `node_modules` directory at the root of the CI build, and the project was being built inside of this directory.

```
node_modules/<project npm package name>/{node_modules,grunt/webpack/...configs}
```

Therefore, it seems the loader was being looked for in the wrong `node_modules` directory, but it is strange that other loaders that I was using such as `babel` and `handlebars` were being sourced correctly.

When I used the loader path directly in the loader config

```
var injectFilenamePath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'grunt/webpack/inject-filename-loader');
console.log('LOADER PATH => ', injectFilenamePath);

var loaders = [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: [
        /node_modules/,
        /bower_components/,
        /libraries/
      ],
      loader: injectFilenamePath + '?' + opts.injectFileNameParams
    },
    { test: /\.hbs$/, loader: 'handlebars-loader' },
    {test: /\.js?$/, exclude: ['bower_components', 'node_modules'], loader: 'babel-loader'}
  ];
```

the console output was

```
LOADER PATH =>  /opt/tmp/node_modules/marketing-website/grunt/webpack/inject-filename-loader
```

and after cloning our repo rather than `npm i` the path was

```
LOADER PATH =>  /opt/tmp/marketing-website/grunt/webpack/inject-filename-loader
```

Not sure if this somehow expected behavior but hopefully it saves others from similar issues if they arise.