# webpack alternative to requirejs' module.config()

Tags: javascript, requirejs, webpack

in requirejs there is a way to configure modules [configure modules](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-moduleconfig), so the configuration is available in the module using `module.config()`.
what's webpack's alternative?

Comment: Prabably you can find your answer here: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html

Comment: @OrryVandermeulen I couldn't find anything, that's why I ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack doesn't provide any specific mechanism for this. We can build one on top of it, though. Webpack allows us to [get current __filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553868/current-file-path-in-webpack). As discussed in that answer, after doing

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  node: {
    __filename: true
  }
}
```

Accessing `__filename` at a module will give us path to it.

We can combine this idea with [resolve.alias](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias). Example configuration:

```
{
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      config: path.join(__dirname, './config')
    }
  }
}
```

After this we can do

```
var config = require('config')(__filename);
```

and you can return the module specific configuration you want from your configuration module.

Comment: resolve.alias is not module-specific as I understand

Comment: I'm not sure I get the point. You can use it to point at some directory to perform lookups below it or alternatively you can point to an individual file in which case it would map that directly instead.

Comment: the point is that in requirejs you can configure each module with it's own configuration, which is later available in the module by calling `module.config()`

Comment: @zowers Got it. We can do something similar through modules. I'll expand my answer with the basic idea.

Comment: @zowers I added a proposed solution. It's probably not as nice as the one you get through requirejs but it should work.

Comment: this somehow emulates requirejs' config but is not as easy to understand and use. also it does not allow sending dynamic configuration. probably the main answer to the question is as you put it: "Webpack doesn't provide any specific mechanism for this".

Comment: Yeah. It might be possible to [implement a plugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/plugins.html) that gets closer to what you want. I would start by figuring out what [ProvidePlugin](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/ProvidePlugin.js) does and then move from there. This way you could for example give a global `config` object that maps to configuration associated with the file.