# How to get current filename without path and extension with webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I can [get the relative file *path*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25565222/65387) with `__filename`, and sure I could hack it apart to get just the basename with some JS-fu, but I want to do this at compile-time.

[`DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) will let me inject some globals like I want, but AFAICT I can't have a "dynamic" global based on the current file.

So how can I do this?

e.g. given I am in the file `assets/scripts/lib/components/bpm/RecordAttendancePopup.jsx`, how can I get webpack to inject a constant like `__basename` that evaluates to `"RecordAttendancePopup"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Generic version

If you're using modules or any supported bundler, you can access the pre-existing `import.meta.url` and manually extract the filename:

```js
const filename = import.meta.url // Get current path
  .split(/[\\/]/).pop() // Get current filename
  .replace(/\.[^.]+$/, ''); // Drop extension
```

or you can use a better parser (which may or may not work depending on your config)

```js
const path = require('path');
const filename = path.parse(import.meta.url).name;
```

### Webpack-specific version

This is what I use in my `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            __filebasename: webpack.DefinePlugin.runtimeValue(
                info => JSON.stringify(path.parse(info.module.resource).name)
            )
        })
    ]
};
```

and then I'll have the `__filebasename` variable available everywhere in my source. Works in Webpack 4 and 5.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no other way than creating your own "DefinePlugin" based on https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/DefinePlugin.js to get what you want.